# Unable to upload test flight due to itune Connect Access

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I am added as Admin in both developer and iTunes connect  account  by my client. First time, I have sent the **testflight** successfully. But second time getting this error

> "No account with iTunes Connect access "

I don't know why i am getting this though i am added as admin. I checked with other SO Q&A. Didn't get the correct solution. Please help me out.

[here is the screen shot link](http://prntscr.com/glrnc0)

Comment: did you try sign out and sign In again in your Xcode?

Comment: did you added apple account in xcode-->preferences-->accounts ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha client added me as admin in both developer and itune connect. I have added my account creds.

Comment: you says that first time you have sent testflight successfully but second time you can't. did you check that you have still admin access ? might be you are remove from admin

Comment: This happens sometimes with Xcode. Go to Xcode -> Preferencec -> Accounts and delete your account and add it again. It worked for me last time when I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we may get this issue if we upload the app through `window -> organize in xCode`. This problem with from apple server I guess.

There is one other way to upload the app in appstore using **Application loader Tool**.

**Check this link on how to upload app using applicaiton loader tool:**

[Upload your app binary files with Application Loader](http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdATD1E12-D1E1A1303-D1E12A1126)

Try this. This may help you out easily.